# How do I clear the isolated storage of another application?

Tags: isolatedstorage, caching-application-block

Application1 uses *Microsoft Enterprise Library Caching Application Block* with **IsolatedStorageBackingStore** to cache data from a database accessed by Internet. The task is to create another Application2 (helper application like "Adobe Flash Player uninstaller") which will be able to clear the cache of Application1 (this will be one of many features of Application2).

The question is - how can Application2 get the caching folder path of Application1 (in order to clear it)?

The path will be something like "`<System Drive>\Documents and Settings\<User>\Local Settings\Application Data\IsolatedStorage\tqli5mdv.xa5\htccao3l.ksb\StrongName.1r3fiexsbrusebdd0maaohl2i5cz4lhq\StrongName.mwjgo5cc1qomwe5tbepbfnyucq0obm3f\Files\<BackingStore PartitionName>`"?

It's a pity, but the User has several applications with the same `<BackingStore PartitionName>` and this can't be changed, so Application2 can't find this path by `<BackingStore PartitionName>` string (course there will be several folders - one for each application - and I don't know how Application2 can choose which folder belongs to Application1). I was Googled a lot but with no result. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the most recent versions of the Caching block, but previous versions wouldn't allow you to do this. They partition the store by the application's assembly name (amongst other things) so two applications can't see each others data.

Comment: Thx for the reply. I thought there is a way of getting path to the cache. I don't need to see other application data, I want to clear other application cache. http://www.eggheadcafe.com/index/System.IO_Source_f8adb5a3-d675-4cd3-8c8c-3784a3c745cd.asp I know this tool can help, but link to full source is broken :(

Comment: Is it possible to share the cache, if you define the cache as a per-User one then, presumably both applications will have the same cache location. (I haven't tried it though)